# Android Navigate back inside Activity's fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, back

Android provides user navigation using back icon or icon on ActionBar

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and AndroidManifest.xml has

```
        <!--
        since 4.0 
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        --> 
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activity.MainActivity" />
```

Now if my Activity has 3 fragments 1-2-3, 
how to enable back navigation to come back 3->2->1 ?

**When user presses back, how to go to previous fragment, not activity?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pop the fragment by name. While adding fragments to the back stack, just give them a name.

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragB");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragC");
```

Then in Fragment_C, pop the back stack using the name ie.. fragB and include `POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE`

```
someButtonInC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        FragmentManager fm = getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack ("fragB", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you may have **several accessible fragments** inside an application. So you need a *robust* and *infallible* solution. I found a complete and explained solution at the page [Managing the Fragment Back Stack](https://medium.com/@bherbst/managing-the-fragment-back-stack-373e87e4ff62) with the related code in [GitHub](https://github.com/bherbst/FragmentBackStackSample).